# Undefined method "respond_to_mobile_request" using Mobylette in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, mobile, desktop

I'm trying to learn a way to have an app that detects whether you are in a desktop or mobile device, so it can load the corresponding views. I found about the Mobylette gem. I installed it following every step. Added gem "mobylette" to the gemfile, then executed the bundle. After that, I modified the application_controller and finally, i created the .mobile.erb views.

The problem is that now my app is completly useless. Because every time I try to enter to an url, for examlple "http://localhost:3000/teams", throws an **undefined method `respond_to_mobile_requests' for ApplicationController:Class**, which it shouldn't because with Mobylette is supposedly supported.

This is my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    respond_to_mobile_requests :skip_xhr_requests => false
end
```

Comment: restarted the server?

Comment: Tried, but keeps failing

Comment: Which version of the gem are you on? From the docs: "Mobylette 2.0+ deprecated the respond_to_mobile_requests method.
Now you must use `include Mobylette::RespondToMobileRequests` instead."

Comment: I have Mobylette 3.5, I tried adding that line but kept me throwing error. But in this case, it says "undefined method `before_filter' for ApplicationController:Class
Did you mean?  before_action"